# REST api for database driven mobile app

Tags: json, django, database, cordova, rest

I am developing a django web app(just for fun/learning) where users can sign up, ask questions on a certain topic and provide answers. It is all working just fine but I want to learn mobile app development so looked into moving that web app to be a mobile app using phonegap or something similar (recommendations welcome).

From my research it seems that, in order to serve up the data to the mobile app, as REST API would need to send the data as JSON which would be displayed in the app, at least for Phonegap anyway.

Would I be right in thinking that converting the django app to just be a REST API which serves the JSON to the app is the right way of going about things or have I gotten the wrong idea? (I am just learning the concepts of REST apis so apologies if that makes no sense).

Perhaps another framework would be better for creating the API or another approach all together?

I am not tied to any language or framework as I am just using the project to learn.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a PhoneGap app you don't want to use Django to render the HTML, you just want the PhoneGap app to authenticate and communicate to Django via an a web service (here a REST interface, in JSON format e.g.)

This is one possible way to implement REST server on Django: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected would happen if I went with a phonegap implementation. I take it from your answer then that I am not too far off the mark which is good to hear.